# FirstOrDefault in a Join with QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate

First of all, I'm new to NHibernate. I have searched about the QueryOver thing in many pages, but the most profitable page to me has been http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html. Thanks to it, I have arrived to a "semi-solution" I think, but I need this solution to be better.

I have these classes:

```
public class Variable
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set; }
    public virtual string Nombre { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ValorVariable> Valores { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Temporal { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Eliminado{ get; set; }
}

public class ValorVariable
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set; }
    public virtual int IdVariable { get; set; }
    public virtual Variable Variable { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime FechaValor { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Valor { get; set; }
}

public class VariableLigera
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public bool Temporal { get; set; }
    public Decimal Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Variable is the "important" class, that, among other things, have a IList of "ValorVariable"s, that have a value("Valor") and a value date("FechaValor"). "VariableLigera" is like a "light" class of variable, that have some properties of Variable and one value of the ValorVariable List. I hope that is clear.

To populate VariableLigera, I'm trying to do a QueryOver. I would like to do something like this:

```
Variable variableAlias = null;
VariableLigera variableLigeraAlias = null;

var result = _session
            .QueryOver(() => variableAlias ).Where(x => x.Eliminado == false)
            .Select(
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias .Id).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias .Id),
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias .Nombre).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias .Nombre),
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias .Descripcion).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias .Descripcion),
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias .Temporal).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias .Temporal),
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias .Valores.FirstOrDefault().Valor).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias .Valor)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<VariableLigera>())
            .List<VariableLigera>();
```

And here is the problem. I would like to put into the property "Valor" of the variableLigeraAlias the FirstOrDefault value of the Valores list of variableLigera. But it throws an exception, "function FirstOrDefault not recognized".

So I tried another thing, create an alias to ValorVariable and join it to the query. Like this:

```
Variable variableAlias = null;
VariableLigera variableLigeraAlias = null;
ValorVariable valorVariableAlias = null;
var result = _session
            .QueryOver(() => variableAlias).Where(x => x.Eliminado == false)
            .JoinAlias(() => variableAlias.Valores, () => valorVariableAlias)
            .Select(
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Id),
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Nombre).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Nombre),
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Descripcion).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Descripcion),
                Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Temporal).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Temporal),
                Projections.Property(() => valorVariableAlias.Valor).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Valor)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<VariableLigera>())
            .List<VariableLigera>();
```

With this query, I get results, but I get each variable many times(one duplicate per value in the ValoresVariables list). For example, if one variable have 3 values, the query will return 3 "VariablesLigera"s with the 3 values, but I only want one with the first value of it's list.

In short, and to make it clear, I would like to have one result per variable with the firstordefault value in the values("Valor") list. Is it possible using QueryOver? Thanks a lot.

PS: Since english it's not my native language, maybe some things are not much understandable. Feel free to ask if any doubt. Thanks again.

Comment: Why not have a separate mapping for VariableLigera, instead of using projecttion?
If you do have separate mapping you could put in a formula or where clause in the mapping!!

Comment: Can you please try reducing your code down to the [minimum code needed to reproduce the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: does this belong on [codereview.se]?

Comment: @hometoast: Why would it? The code is not working currently...

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, aye, I did read the it through a bit hastily the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing to remember with QueryOver queries in general is that they're ultimately turned into SQL. With this in mind, whenever you access a nested property, you need to think in terms of joins or subqueries to get the job done.

In this case, you need to use a subquery to get the first `ValorVariable.Valor`:

```
Variable variableAlias = null;
VariableLigera variableLigeraAlias = null;

var result = _session
    .QueryOver(() => variableAlias).Where(x => x.Eliminado == false)
    .Select(
        Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Id),
        Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Nombre).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Nombre),
        Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Descripcion).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Descripcion),
        Projections.Property(() => variableAlias.Temporal).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Temporal),
        Projections.Subquery(
            QueryOver.Of<ValorVariable>()
                .Where(vv => vv.Variable.Id == variableAlias.Id)
                .Select(vv => vv.Valor)
                .Take(1)
        ).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Valor)
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<VariableLigera>())
    .List<VariableLigera>();
```

This would generate SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    /*Variable properties */
    (       
        SELECT 
            TOP(1) this_0_.Valor AS y0_ 
        FROM 
            ValorVariable this_0_ 
        WHERE 
            this_0_.VariableID = this_.ID
    ) AS y1_ 
FROM 
    Variable this_ 
WHERE 
    this_.Eliminado = 0
```

Now, as @Carl points out, you probably should order your subquery results by something so that taking the "first record" actually means something.

To do that, you could add an `OrderBy` to the subquery:

```
QueryOver.Of<ValorVariable>()
    .Where(vv => vv.Variable.Id == variableAlias.Id)
    .Select(vv => vv.Valor)
    .OrderBy(vv => vv.FechaValor).Desc
    .Take(1)
```

Which would generate similar SQL, except with an `ORDER BY` clause.

Also, since you were using `FirstOrDefault`, that implies that there's a chance that the `Valor` property could be `null`. If this is the case, you should update your `VariableLigera.Valor` property to be a `decimal?` (nullable `decimal`) instead.

Comment: This looks a bit cleaner than my answer.

Comment: Perfect, works great! Thanks a lot. I didn't thought in terms of subqueries. Maybe it's a good practice to write the query in SQL before putting it in Hibernate.

Thanks again.

Comment: @xecollons: Yep, that's a really good idea, it makes writing QueryOver much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, `VariableLigera` is functioning as DTO for the entity `Variable`.  You want most of the properties of `Variable`, and one value of the `Valores` collection.
  Unless you want any value of the collection, you'll need to specify the criteria for choosing the first value.  Since `VariableValor` has a date property, let's use that to select the most recent value.

Here's a stab at doing this with a subquery.

Untested code (it compiles, but I haven't executed it:

```
Variable variableAlias = null;
VariableLigera variableLigeraAlias = null;
ValorVariable valorVariableAlias = null;
var result = _session
        .QueryOver(() => variableAlias).Where(x => x.Eliminado == false)
        .JoinAlias(() => variableAlias.Valores, () => valorVariableAlias)
        .SelectList(projections => projections
            .Select(() => variableAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Id),
            .Select(() => variableAlias.Nombre).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Nombre),
            .Select(() => variableAlias.Descripcion).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Descripcion),
            .Select(() => variableAlias.Temporal).WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Temporal),

            .SelectSubQuery(QueryOver.Of<ValorVariable>( () => valorVariableAlias)
                                .Where(vv => vv.IdVariable == variableAlias.Id)
            .Select(Projections.Max<ValorVariable>(vv => vv.FechaValor)))
                                .Select(Projections.Property(() => valorVariableAlias.Valor))
           .WithAlias(() => variableLigeraAlias.Valor)
        )
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<VariableLigera>())
        .List<VariableLigera>();
```

Comment: Thanks! I have marked Whitaker's reply as the answer, but this is great too.